# wso2 File WSO2METRICS_DB.h2.db can purge or delete?

Tags: wso2

File WSO2METRICS_DB.h2.db (/opt/wso2/wso2am-X.X.X/repository/database/)
Can delete or purge? I found the size of this file fast growing.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable metrics unless you have a metrics requirement [1].

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Enabling+Metrics+and+Storage+Types